# Find co-occurrence of elements

Tags: python, algorithm, combinatorics

My input consists of a list of lists (not necessary of the same length), like

```
[
     ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'b'],
     ['a', 'd', 'e', 'b'],
     ['f', 'a', 'g', 'e', 'b', 'h']
]
```

and I would like to have a matrix / dictionary  that contains the co-occurences. The keys of the dictionary are the elements of the original matrix, while the values would be a counter. So in the previous example, the result would be

```
{
    'a' : Counter({'b': 4, 'c': 1, 'd': 2, 'e' : 2, 'f' : 1, 'g' : 1, 'h' : 1})
    ...
}
```

Here is my code:

```
import collections
def my_func(data):
    result = collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)
    for l in data:
        for e in l:
            result[e].update([el for el in l if el is not e])
    return result    
my_func(data)
```

This works, except the fact I am not sure it's the smartest way: when updating the Counter, I am relooping over the elements of `l`.

EDIT: I should probably clarify that the elements in the list are not necessary `char`s but Python objects. I have used single letters only for faster typing.

Comment: Please don't use single letter _variable names_ for faster typing, as you've done here. the `el for el in l if el is not e` doesn't read very well!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider the following potential row in your data:

```
'abbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'
```

The bare minimum amount of work necessary would be to add 15 to both results - but with your loop as written, you'd add 15 to `result['a']['b']`, but then add 1 to `result['b']['a']` 15 times. That's less than ideal.

So let's first condense the row into a counter - and then add the counter itself:

```
result = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(int))

for row in data:
    counts = collections.Counter(row)
    for key_from, key_to in itertools.permutations(counts, 2):
        result[key_from][key_to] += counts[key_from] * counts[key_to]
```

[`permutations()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) gives us all the pairs of keys that we will need to update - without repeat to ensure that a letter does not co-occur with itself. Of course, if the row is `'abcdefgh'`, this won't do us any good - we still make \$N^2\$ passes. But if the row is the first one I suggested, it's a big improvement.

Regardless, this:

```
result[e].update([el for el in l if el is not e])
```

Can be improved by removing the `[]`s:

```
result[e].update(el for el in l if el is not e)
```

`update()` can take an iterable, so no need to create a full list.

Comment: This is interesting, especially for the use of the nested `defaultdics`. I wonder if we could avoid using `permutations` and use `combinations` instead to cut in half the innermost loop (by adding the appropriate extra assignment for `result`)

Comment: @meto Sounds like it'd be a good thing to try!

Answer (score 4):

You have some readability issues. Your names tell me nothing about what this is doing. `my_func`, `l`, and `e` are all names that obfuscate your code. Consider renaming them:

```
def calculate_cooccurrence(data):
    result = collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)

    for line in data:
        for char in line:
            result[char].update([c for c in line if c is not char])
    return result
```

Though instead of `char` name something meaningful, based on what your actual data is. Likewise with `line` if possible. You should also add a docstring. "cooccurence" is not an easily understood word and the code works in a complex way too. Add a docstring so that a user can understand the idea of your code.

```
def calculate_cooccurrence(data):
    """Return a dictionary of Counter objects with the cooccurence count.

    Co-occurence counts how many times a particular element is in the 
    same line as another element across the full data set."""
```

Also do you need to return as a `defaultdict`? Consider returning as a plain dictionary at the end of your function if you no longer need the default values.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I was more concerned with the actual algorithm rather that the naming. which I agree, I should change and improve